# How to make a pirate plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have data which looks like this:

```
       Age New_York Boston Chicago
1  under 1      994    969    1011
2        1      991   1094    1282
3        2      991   1369    1274
4        3      818   1051    1098
5        4      902   1012    1308
6        5      866   1077    1040
7        6      826   1684     929
8        7      793   1071    1077
9        8      714   1387     984
10       9      890    855     749
```

This is the code to produce my data:

```
structure(list(Age = c("under 1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9"), New_York = c("994", "991", "991", "818", "902", 
"866", "826", "793", "714", "890"), Boston = c("969", "1094", 
"1369", "1051", "1012", "1077", "1684", "1071", "1387", "855"
), Chicago = c("1011", "1282", "1274", "1098", "1308", "1040", 
"929", "1077", "984", "749")), .Names = c("Age", "New_York", 
"Boston", "Chicago"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to produce a pirate plot in R which would have Age as the IV and the answers for the different cities.I would like to know what the code is to do this in R

Comment: Do you have a specific package in mind? Have you tried anything? LucieD, questions that only say "code this for me for free" sometimes get answers but often are avoided or down-voted: this is not a free-code service. It would help immensely if you show some more research and effort on your part. (And if you say "I don't know what package", please realize that SO specifically marks questions asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial"* as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, it looks like your values under the cities are characters. You need to make sure they are numeric first. Then you need to convert your data from wide to long, after which you can simply use `geom_pirate` from the `ggpirate` package:

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("mikabr/ggpirate")
library(ggpirate)

df_long <- gather(df_wide[,c(2:4)], key = "City", value = "Value")

ggplot(df_long, aes(City, Value)) +
  geom_pirate(aes(col = City), show.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Note that I named your original data set `df_wide` and changed the `char`s to `num`s in them.

EDIT: Alternatively you can use the `pirateplot()` function from the `yarrr` package:

```
library(yarrr)
df <- structure(list(Age = c("under 1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
                       "7", "8", "9"), New_York = c("994", "991", "991", "818", "902", 
                                                    "866", "826", "793", "714", "890"), Boston = c("969", "1094", 
                                                                                                   "1369", "1051", "1012", "1077", "1684", "1071", "1387", "855"
                                                    ), Chicago = c("1011", "1282", "1274", "1098", "1308", "1040", 
                                                                   "929", "1077", "984", "749")), .Names = c("Age", "New_York", 
                                                                                                             "Boston", "Chicago"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
df$New_York <- as.numeric(df$New_York)
df$Boston <- as.numeric(df$Boston)
df$Chicago <- as.numeric(df$Chicago)

df_long <- gather(df[,c(2:4)], key = "City", value = "Value")

pirateplot(formula = Value ~ City,
           data = df_long)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer @Sven - is there a way a different package in R that would also allow me to produce a pirate plot, as ggpirate requires R 3.4, which is a version I don't have.

Comment: @LucieD, I've added an alternative. You could of course also just upgrade your R version?

Comment: Given that a pirate plot is nothing else than boxplot + scatter plot + density plot, it should be trivial in ggplot2 without ggpirate as well.

Comment: Try `ggplot(df_long, aes(City, Value, col=City)) + geom_violin() + geom_boxplot(alpha=0.1) + geom_point(position=position_jitter(0.1))`

Comment: But frankly, I think the pirate plots are too much of a good thing. I would *love* to read what Tufte would have to say about them. Also, you don't need color coding if you have the same information contained in the visual split / x axis. And adding a bar plot to all of that is just... this is just... madness.